# Adjusting 3D-view in pgfplots by custom transformation matrix for multiple axes

Tags: pgfplots, overlays, 3d

I'm trying to overlay two axis environments in a tikzpicture for adjustable views.

In principle this wouldn't be a big deal - but, I would like to use this technique for the projection e.g. of text or labels within the xy-plane *without* slanting, sloping etc.

By using the **cm** key the projection works fine, but every 3D-plot within the axis will be flattened. The simple idea has been now, to overlay a *normal* by a *projected* axis (builtin pgfplots view vs. custom rotation matrix). And here my trouble began ... I'm not able to adjust these two different axes for all views.

The attached MWE shows my (failed) attempt ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\azimuth{60}
\def\elevation{40}

\def\RotX{90}
\def\Sc{1/(sin(\azimuth) + cos(\azimuth))}

\def\myplot{\addplot3[surf,domain=-3:3]{exp(-x^2-y^2)};}

\def\mywidth{8cm}
\def\myheight{8cm}

\tikzset{
    xyprojection/.estyle={
        /pgfplots/view={0}{\RotX},
        xscale=\Sc,
        yscale=\Sc,
        yshift=(\myheight/2)*cos(\elevation),
        cm={
            cos(\azimuth),sin(\azimuth)*sin(-\elevation),
            sin(\azimuth)*sin(\RotX),cos(\RotX)*cos(-\elevation)-sin(\RotX)*cos(\azimuth)*sin(-\elevation),
            (0,0)},
        opacity=0.5,
        },
    normalview/.style={
        /pgfplots/view={\azimuth}{\elevation},
        opacity=0.5,
    },
}
\pgfplotsset{
    myaxis/.style={
        width=\mywidth,
        height=\myheight,
        enlargelimits=0,
        scale only axis,
    },
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    % *** projected plot based on cm ***
    \begin{scope}[xyprojection]
        \begin{axis}[myaxis]
            \myplot
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

    % *** normal plot based on view ***
    \begin{scope}[normalview]
        \begin{axis}[myaxis,hide axis]
            \myplot
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

So you are trying to sync the pgfplots cm with that of tikz, and it fails somewhere? What if we manage to avoid this challenge and get the desired effect by means of a slightly different approach?

My idea is to apply the slanting to the tick labels *only* and to rely on the standard formatting of `pgfplots` to compute the CM as such.

I implemented the idea by modifying your approach; perhaps it helps you to fit the result to your needs:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\def\azimuth{60}
\def\elevation{40}

\def\RotX{90}
\def\Sc{1/(sin(\azimuth) + cos(\azimuth))}

\def\myplot{\addplot3[surf,domain=-3:3]{exp(-x^2-y^2)};}

\def\mywidth{8cm}
\def\myheight{8cm}

\def\ZMAX{1.5}

\pgfplotsset{
    xyprojection/.estyle={
        view={\azimuth}{\elevation},
        z filter/.expression=-1,
        point meta=rawz,
        zmin=-1,
        zmax=\ZMAX,
        hide z axis,
        axis lines*=left,
        ticklabel style={
            cm={
                cos(\azimuth),sin(\azimuth)*sin(-\elevation),
                sin(\azimuth)*sin(\RotX),cos(\RotX)*cos(-\elevation)-sin(\RotX)*cos(\azimuth)*sin(-\elevation),
                (0,0)},
        },
        opacity=0.5,
    },
    normalview/.style={
        view={\azimuth}{\elevation},
        zmin=-1,
        zmax=\ZMAX,
        opacity=0.5,
    },
}
\pgfplotsset{
    myaxis/.style={
        width=\mywidth,
        height=\myheight,
        enlargelimits=0,
        scale only axis,
    },
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    % *** projected plot based on cm ***
        \begin{axis}[xyprojection,myaxis,anchor=origin]
            \myplot
        \end{axis}

    % *** normal plot based on view ***
        \begin{axis}[normalview,myaxis,hide axis,anchor=origin]
            \myplot
        \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I did is to overlay two axes. I ensured that they have the same limits in all directions and I "simulated" the XY projection on a higher level of abstraction (namely by mapping the Z coordinate of your surf plot to -1). I also added `point meta=rawz` such that it uses the "raw" z value and not the transformed one in order to derive the color.

The outcome is: the CMs are synced, the tick labels appear to be as in your example. There are a couple of warnings about tick label anchors; I ignored them for now.

Comment: I didn't know that you can simply formulate the ticklabel style in that way. This is nice. Thanks. - But I'm looking for a more general solution, e.g., the projection of text / annotations / labels ... And here I have had success specifying the projection showing in my MWE. Text nodes are projected in the right way, Since the projected axes will be _always_ flattened I thought to overlay the 3D-pgf-view! - but this "sync" failed. - Does exist a similar solution as in the ticklabels case for annotations?

Comment: I suppose that your CM is just "almost" the same as is used by pgfplots. If you manage to determine the very same one combined with your flattening + skew transformation, it should be fine, I suppose. However, I do not have time to think about it right now. My solution looks good even if the CMs are just partially in sync -- the small differences are hard to notice for the single text nodes. In other words: I am sure there is a solution as yours, it might just need more time to find it.

Comment: I am wondering if it works to extract the cm of pgfplots and copy + adopt it to your example... (perhaps combined with `disabledatascaling`?) but I do not have time to experiment with this approach